# Java API for vsd or vdx file generation

Tags: java, export, visio

Is there any library to generate Visio files from Java?

DatadiagramML schema (vdx) is availible on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23976, but it looks very complicated and I hope for any API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Options for You:

### VisioAutomation.VDX

I wrote a library called "VisioAutomation.VDX" that may be of some help to you. It is written in C# but should be a straightforward conversion to Java.

You can get the source code here: https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation

### pkgVisio

http://pkgvisio.codeplex.com/

For the Visio 2013 XML format

Comment: Thx for this options, I'll try to use it if there is no other options for Java.

Comment: Could you provide any code samples of VisioAutomation.VDX usage?

Comment: Take a look at the TestVisioAutomation.VDX Project at the codeplex project site. The Unit Tests serve as good examples of how to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Visio's own API is a COM API therefore if your application is on Windows you could use a Java to COM bridge and use Visio to generate the drawings. You may have to purchase a Visio license for each PC running you application and there are licensing restrictions on using this method in a server scenario.

An alternative which you may want to consider is using a library which generates a non-Visio file format Visio supports such as SVG.